# Scrapy scraping using a loop

Tags: loops, web-scraping, scrapy

I would like to scrape information from http://www.stfrancismedical.org/asp/job-summary.asp?cat=4, but I don't know how since what I know only is recursive scraping. Is there a way to scrape or get all information of each job using loops?

Or any other idea would be great.

Comment: Hi. Just so you know, we do expect a minimum level of research for questions here. How to scrape a site is a broad topic, and requires a fair bit of research and practice. You are substantially in luck this time, since someone has done 95% of the work for you - but nevertheless, it is better if you can demonstrate what you have done in your questions.

Answer (score 1):

The structure of that page is a bit strange. A table with all its rows in the same level depth. It makes the `xpath` more difficult to extract all the data for each job at the same time. My approach is to use the module operator and fill the `item` object for each cycle.

Regardless of that, the page has no links so it's very straighforward to use a spider.

First step, create the project:

```
scrapy startproject stfrancismedical
cd stfrancismedical
```

Second step, create the spider:

```
scrapy genspider -t basic stfrancismedical_spider 'stfrancismedical.org'
```

Third step, create the `item` with all fields of a job:

```
vim stfrancismedical/items.py
```

With new content like:

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class StfrancismedicalItem(Item):
    department = Field()
    employment = Field()
    shift = Field()
    weekends_holidays = Field()
    biweekly_hours = Field()
    description = Field()
    requirements = Field()
```

Fourth step, edit the spider:

```
vim stfrancismedical/spiders/stfrancismedical_spider.py
```

With content:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from stfrancismedical.items import StfrancismedicalItem

rn = ('department', 'employment', 'shift', 'weekends_holidays',
        'biweekly_hours', 'description', 'requirements')

class StfrancismedicalSpiderSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "stfrancismedical_spider"
    allowed_domains = ["stfrancismedical.org"]
    start_urls = ( 
        'http://www.stfrancismedical.org/asp/job-summary.asp?cat=4',
    )   


    def parse(self, response):
        items = []
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        for i, tr in enumerate(hxs.select('/html/body/div/table//tr[count(./td)=2]')):
            if (i % 7 == 0): 
                if (i > 0): items.append(item)
                item = StfrancismedicalItem()
            idx = i % 7 
            item[rn[idx]] = tr.select('./td[2]//text()').extract()[0]
        else:
            items.append(item)
        return items
```

And run it like:

```
scrapy crawl stfrancismedical_spider -o stfrancismedical.json -t json
```

That creates a new file `stfrancismedical.json` with data:

```
[{"requirements": "Skilled in Cath Lab nursing, 2 years experience and patient recovery experience. A Current valid NJ RN license with a current ACLS certification.", "description": "Responsible for the delivery of individualized patient care to assigned patients utilizing the nursing process of assessment, planning, implementation and evaluation.", "shift": "Day - Evening - Night", "biweekly_hours": "Varied", "weekends_holidays": "No", "department": "Cardiac Care", "employment": "Pool"},
{"requirements": "Requirements: A Current valid NJ RN license with a current ACLS & BLS certification.", "description": "Responsible for the delivery of individualized patient care to assigned critical care patients utilizing the nursing process of assessment, planning, implementation and evaluation. ", "shift": "Evening", "biweekly_hours": "72", "weekends_holidays": "Yes", "department": "Critical Care Unit", "employment": "Full-Time"},
{"requirements": "ACLS, NJ License required.\u00a0 Balloon pump certification preferred.", "description": "Provide comprehensive Nursing care to critically ill patients.\u00a0 ", "shift": "Day", "biweekly_hours": "72 - 11am - 11pm", "weekends_holidays": "Yes", "department": "Critical Care Unit", "employment": "Full-Time"},
{"requirements": "ACLS, NJ License required.\u00a0 Balloon pump certification preferred.", "description": "Provide comprehensive Nursing care to critically ill patients. ", "shift": "Evening - Night", "biweekly_hours": "72 - 7pm - 7am", "weekends_holidays": "No", "department": "Critical Care Unit", "employment": "Full-Time"},
{"requirements": "Associates Degree in Nursing, Healthcare, or equivalent experience: BSN preferred.", "description": "Must be detail oriented and able to follow detailed procedures to ensure accuracy.\u00a0 Must demonstrate excellent follow up skills.\u00a0 Ability to coordinate and priortize multiple duties.\u00a0 Understands interactions amongst clinical areas and their roles within hospital.\u00a0 Advanced knowledge in computer skills, including knowledge of Microsoft Word, Excel and PowerPoint.\u00a0", "shift": "Day", "biweekly_hours": "80", "weekends_holidays": "No", "department": "Nursing Education", "employment": "Full-Time"},
...
```

Comment: what is the logic behind the modulo of 7? I only wanted to get the job  title (like RN), department, and the linkaddress(apply now) of each table.

Comment: @chano: Extract all information of each job offer, which has seven sections each one. As [halfer](http://stackoverflow.com/users/472495/halfer) said in comments, to extract only two will be easier from here.